# What does "run-time representation" means in programming languages"?

Tags: runtime, programming-languages, representation

I'm taking a "Programming Languages: Design and Implementation" course and want to know what "run-time representation" means in programming languages?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Run-time representation of what? In what context is the phrase used, and what exactly is it that you don't understand about it?

Comment: @svick It's also referred to as implementation or run-time representation of constructs or also storage representation, I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking. It's used in studying programming languages: design and implementation. I don't understand what it stands for exactly and its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

To understand it, you need to remember that (contemporary) computers only know integral numbers (in various lengths: 1, 2, 4 or 8 bytes), IEEE floating point numbers (4 or 8 bytes) and memory addresses (pointers, 4 or 8 bytes).

Thus when you want to have a list, for example, you (or, at least the compiler writer of the language you are using) need to think about how  lists will be represented (!) in memory at runtime.

One possible representation for elements of singly linked lists:

```
|________|________|
DataPtr   NextPtr
```

The list node takes two adjacent pointer sized memory words, the first one points to the actual data, the second word points to the next list node.

There are two things to note here:

1. The representation is quite arbitrary. For example, we could switch the data and the next pointer, and this would be another representation that is as good as the former one.
2. Consider the run-time representation of a tuple or pair. It could be:

   |________|________|

   PtrFirst  PtrSecond

   that is, two memory words that hold pointers to the first and second component, respectively. Sounds familiar?

   Well, how can we tell whether two subsequent words that hold pointers represent a pair or a list element? We can't! Many of our data abstraction will end up using the same run-time representation.